# Full screen invisible ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I'm experiencing a fullscreen, invisible ad on stackoverflow. Here's a screenshot from Inspect Element with my location omitted:

[image]

The `a` occupies 100% of the window height and 100% of the width. It doesn't appear on every page, but when it does, it means that on my first click on the page, I am redirected to employmentalert.com. This is very obtrusive.

How do I stop this from appearing?

Comment: As Cerbrus points out, we would never do such a thing. You almost certainly picked up malware and should take action to clear it. Some sleazy ISP's have also been known to inject ads into unsecure pages. If using https causes them to go away, that might be the cause.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*"How do I stop this from appearing?"*

Scan your PC for malware / Viruses.
If that doesn't work, get a fresh installation of your browser.

Ads like that aren't permitted by SO, and are probably originated from an issue on your end.

Comment: And use an incognito browsing session to exclude browser plugins. Not all malware plugins are picked up by malware scanners. HoverZoom for example did things like this.

Comment: I've tracked it down to an iframe that occupies the whole window with src https://target-talent.com/widget/11/main.html . Doesn't appear to be there in Incognito so I'll be taking a closer look at my extensions.

Comment: Tracked it down to an Imgur Uploader extension. It's been conveniently removed from the extension store.... heh.

Comment: I have the same issue, also had this imgur extension installed